# Running PHP exec() in IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis-7.5

If I run this PHP script on a browser (the server is IIS 7.5):

```
<?php
exec("someProg.exe");
?>
```

Which user does the process (`someProg.exe`) belong to? Is it `IUSR`?

Another question: if `someProg.exe` needs some .DLLs from `system32` folder, will I be able to run it if the process belongs to `IUSR`?

Edit: the IIS version is 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

For sure, the process belongs to `IUSR`. Just checked that in the server's Task Manager. And I just found out that `IUSR` actually has access to `system32`. I tried this in PHP:

```
<?php
echo exec("whoami");          // whoami.exe is in system32 folder
?>
```

It will display `IUSR` on the browser page.